# Why can't I directly manipulate a pandas DataFrame in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

```
full_data = [train, test]
for dataset in full_data:
     dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset)
```

I am trying to do one-hot-encoding of both my train & test pandas DataFrames. It turned out that neither the train or the test DataFrame was changed. Could I get some help here on why this does not work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Basically, what you are doing in this loop is to iterate over the list, name first item of the list `dataset`, then name another thing `dataset`. What you can do is simply create a new list: `full_data = [pd.get_dummies(dataset) for dataset in full_data]`

Comment: Great article on Python names and values. This solved my puzzle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
full_data = pd.concat([train,test])

df_new = pd.get_dummies(full_data, 
                        columns=categorical_columns, 
                        drop_first=True)
```

Comment: `for dataset in full_data:
    dataset.loc[:,dataset.dtypes=='int64'] = norm(dataset.loc[:,dataset.dtypes=='int64'])' This very similar piece of code does the purpose of normalising my data.  I am trying to understand why you can change some specific columns but you can't change the whole dataset.